# Django testing environment is missing Group and Permissions: but I created them in a migration

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to fix a bunch of tests in a codebase, which are failing due to not having permissions (for ex: update ticket). The weird thing is, I have a migration in place which creates auth Groups and adds the appropriate Permissions to the Groups.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental in Django's test environment setup - I thought it applies migrations before running tests, and that **migrations** are a preferred way over **fixtures** for something like this where the Group should always 1. exist and 2. have that Permission.

**The Migration**

```py
from django.db import migrations
from django.core.management.sql import emit_post_migrate_signal

def create_groups(apps, schema_editor):
    # Ensure permissions and content types have been created.
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    emit_post_migrate_signal(2, False, db_alias)

    Permission = apps.get_model("auth", "Permission")
    Group = apps.get_model("auth", "Group")

    # Create CC group
    permission = Permission.objects.get(
        codename="handle_ticket", content_type__model="ticket"
    )
    corps = Group.objects.create(name="CC")
    corps.permissions.add(permission)

def remove_groups(apps, schema_editor):
    Group = apps.get_model("auth", "Group")
    cc = Group.objects.filter(name="CC").delete()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("my_app", "previous"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_groups, remove_groups),
    ]
```

**The test**, which fails with an Auth error.

```py
def test_update_ticket(self):
        ticket = factories.TicketFactory(notes="Old notes")
        cc_group = Group.objects.get(name="CC")
        assignee = factories.UserFactory()
        assignee.groups.set([cc_group])
        self.client.force_login(assignee)

        result = self.client.post(
            reverse("ticket_update", args=[ticket.id]), data={"notes": "New notes"}
        )
        print(assignee.groups.all(), assignee.get_all_permissions(), assignee.has_perm("my_app.handle_ticket")) 
        #### PRINTS: Group(CC), QuerySet[], False 
        #### the QuerySet shouldn't be empty, and .has_perm should be True
```

Comment: Whether all migrations are run for your tests depends on your setup. e.g. you can opt to not re-create your test database to save time. But this should be easy to spot: just look on the console if those migrations are executed when you run the tests.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken where would that show up on the console? ie. after running pytest, it should...what, print a list of all migrations it ran? Before the warnings summary and/or errors?

Comment: yes. here is an example from one of my apps: https://gitlab.com/ErikKalkoken/aa-standingsrequests/-/jobs/2516564728#L141

Comment: If your setup is different an effective hack is to delete the **test** database. That way you can make sure all migrations are run.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken this is good advice! I checked pytest.ini and it was running with `--reuse-db` flag; I tried running with `--create-db` and it worked! Guess it was just a stale db I didn't realize I had used for so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment, I figured out the issue was that I was reusing a test db that didn't have the migrations applied.

To solve this, either check your `pytest.ini` file and make sure `--reuse-db` isn't written in the `addopts` field (note: this may re-build the test db each time you run a test, so it may slow down your testing), or add `--create-db` to the pytest command when you run the test from terminal (to rebuild db this particular test run).